# JS / Backbone - My simple script will not fire "validate" in the base model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In App.Models.Task the validate method will not fire.

TO TEST: Edit a task, then press cancel on the popup window.
When you press edit, you can change the task title.
When you cancel, it should VALIDATE and not remove the task title.

Here it is here on jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/michaelwjoyner/x4xc7rpz/1/

```html
(function(){

  window.App = {
    Models:{},
    Views :{},
    Collections:{}
  };

  window.template =  function(){
    return Handlebars.compile('{{title}} <button class="edit">Edit</button> <button class="delete">Delete</button>');
  };

  App.Models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
    validate: function(attrs) {
      if (! attrs.title) {
        return 'A task requires a title';
      }
    }
  });


  App.Views.Tasks = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    render: function(){
      this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
      return this;
    },
    addOne: function(task){
      // creating a new node view
      var taskView = new App.Views.Task({ model : task });
      // append to the root element
      this.$el.append(taskView.render().el);
    }
  });

  App.Views.Task = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : 'li',
    events  : {
      'click .edit' : 'editTask'
    },
    initialize : function(){
      this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },
    editTask : function(){
      var newTask = prompt('Change task to : ',this.model.get('title') );
      this.model.set('title',newTask);
    },

    render : function () {
      console.log('rendered');
      compiler = template('taskTemplate');
      html = compiler( this.model.toJSON());
      this.$el.html( html );
      return this;
    }
  });

  App.Collections.Task = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model   : App.Models.Task
  });

  var tasksCollection = new App.Collections.Task([
    {
      title: 'Go to the store',
      priority: 4
    },
    {
      title: 'Cut Hair',
      priority: 4
    },
    {
      title: 'Go to Kingdom Hall',
      priority: 4
    },
  ]);

  var tasksView = new App.Views.Tasks( {collection : tasksCollection} );

  $(document).ready( function() {
    $("#tasks").html(tasksView.render().el);
  });

})();
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <!-- Setup our templates -->

    <h1>Tasks</h1>
    <div id="tasks">
    </div>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below alterations to your `editTask` method address the issue of the 'removed task title' on canceling from the prompt.  `prompt` returns null on cancellation (which was causing your issue) as seen here:

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)

Not entirely sure what you mean by 'should VALIDATE', but a comment in the code below recommends the place to validate the new title.

```
editTask: function() {
    var title = this.model.get('title');
    var newTask = prompt('Change task to : ', title);

    if (newTask) {
      // Run your 'validation' code here? If satisfied, set the title

      title = newTask;
    }

    this.model.set('title', title);
},
```

Comment: Backbone is supposed to have a validate method. In my App.Models.Task there is a validate method that is not firing. From the view I can use: this.method.validate, but I want it to work right

Answer (score 0):

use this code.it will work :)

```
this.model.set({ title : newTask}, { validate : true });
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

From the [backbonejs docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate):

> By default save checks validate before setting any attributes but you may also tell set to validate the new attributes by passing {validate: true} as an option.

After your prompt you set the value on the model without telling it to validate.

```
this.model.set('title',newTask);
```

Instead of passing a key,value pair you may also change attributes by providing an object:

```
this.model.set({'title': newTask});
```

Additionally you can pass options to the set method e.g. to signal that you want validation:

```
this.model.set({'title': newTask}, {validate: true});
```

This *will* call your validate method and prevent an empty value being set on the model. However it will not do anything with the message you provided. You can do that by providing a listener for validation errors:

```
this.model.on('invalid', this.onInvalid, this);
```

...

```
onInvalid: function () {
   alert(this.model.validationError);
},
```

Please see the [adaptation of your code](http://codepen.io/akkerman/pen/XjYRKo)